# Triangle formed by positive integral powers of sides of scalene triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

If $a  \geq b \geq c>0$ be real numbers such that $\forall n \in N$, there exists triangles of side lengths $a^n,b^n,c^n$.Then prove that those triangles must be Isosceles.

I am not sure how to prove this, but what i understood from the question is, Given a scalene triangle its impossible that $\forall n \in N$ the sides $a^n,b^n,c^n$ also forms scalene triangle.

First of all, i considered to eliminate Scalene Right triangles, since if $a>b>c$ forms a right scalene triangle we have $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and hence triangle inequality will not be satisfied for $a^2,b^2,c^2$ and hence they wont form a triangle at all.

Also its impossible to form a triangle with squares of sides of Isosceles triangle with sides $a,a,c$ with $c \geq \sqrt{2}a$.

But for Non right angled scalene triangles i am not sure to find $n \in N$ such that $a^n,b^n,c^n$ does not form a triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the triangle is not isosceles. Then $a > b > c > 0$.

We need to show that for sufficiently large $n$, $a^n > b^n + c^n$, which violates the triangle inequality.

Note that $\dfrac {a^n}{b^n + c^n} \ge \dfrac {a^n}{2b^n} = \dfrac12\left(\dfrac ab\right)^n \to \infty$ as $\dfrac ab > 1$.

Thus there exists some large $N$ such that the quotient is larger than $1$, and this completes the proof by contrapositive.

Comment: Hi but as i said even for isosceles triangles there are some restrictions right? For example if the sides chosen are $1,1,1.5$, their squares not forming a triangle.

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla Yes, but that's not what the question says. The question is "Show that these sides form an isosceles triangle", but not "For any isosceles triangle, the following holds". Do you see the difference?